# Creating xml output within Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am using PS 5 version and trying to create xml which should look as below:

```
<ConfigurationItemReport>
    <checkListItemCount>14</checkListItemCount>
    <checkListItems>
        <element>
            <checklistItemId>ID_1</checklistItemId>
            <checklistItemName>Name1</checklistItemName>
        </element>
        <element>
            <checklistItemId>ID_2</checklistItemId>
            <checklistItemName>Name2</checklistItemName>
        </element>
        ....  
    </checkListItems>
    <checkListName>CompCheck</checkListName>
    <serverIp>11.113.144.12</serverIp>
</ConfigurationItemReport>
```

I have written the following powershell 5.0 script so far which is not creating the xml

```
$allout = @()

$allout += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{

    checklistItemName = 'Name1'
}

$output = [ordered]@{

    serverHostname = $serverhostname
    checkListItems = $allout
}

foreach ($check in $allout) {
    $check.checkListItemName  

    $hash = @{
        "Enclosure Model Type" = $check.checkListItemName  
    }
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $hash
    Export-Clixml -Path E:\WindowsOAC\test.xml
}
```

Comment: `Export-CliXml` is going to tag it with all kinds of type information intended to be re-imported with `Import-CliXml`.  Do you strictly want the output to be like your example?

Comment: the output can have more elements as well but elements name remain same

Comment: What is the intended use of the output xml?

Comment: it will be supplied as an input to another script written in different language which will parse the xml

Comment: Which language?  Might be easier to go the JSON route.

Comment: python is the language

Comment: I'd suggest using json: `$object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth [int32]::MaxValue | Out-File -FilePath 'out.json'`

Comment: I am getting the error `ConvertTo-Json : Cannot bind parameter 'Depth'. Cannot convert value "[int32]::MaxValue" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At script.ps1:442 char:44
+               $obj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth [int32]::MaxValue | Out-Fi ...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-Json], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToJsonCommand`

Comment: wrap that argument in parenthesis

Comment: `$object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth ([int32]::MaxValue) | Out-File -FilePath 'out.json' ` still getting an error

Comment: The same error or a different one?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of utilizing `xml`, I'd suggest using `json` for language interop since your intention for this is serialization to be used from `powershell` in `python`.  `powershell` has a built-in `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet which will output your object as a string which can then be output to file.  By default, it only goes two layers deep into your object, but that can be customized with the `-Depth` parameter (it accepts an `int32` argument):

```
$MyObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 | Out-File -FilePath C:\myfile.json
```